# What are the properties of eigenvalues of permutation matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutation-cycles, permutation-matrices

Up till now, the only things I was able to come up/prove are the following properties:

- $\prod\lambda_i = \pm 1$
- $ 0 \leq \sum \lambda_i \leq n$, where $n$ is the size of the matrix
- eigenvalues of the permutation matrix lie on the unit circle

I am curious whether there exist some other interesting properties.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A permutation matrix is an orthogonal matrix (orthogonality of column vectors and norm of column vectors = 1).

As such, because an orthogonal matrix "is" an isometry

$$\tag{1}\|PV\|=\|V\|$$

If $V$ is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$, substituting $PV=\lambda V$ in (1) we deduce

$$|\lambda|=1.$$

Moreover, as $P^p=I_n$ ($p$ is the order of the permutation) these eigenvalues are such that $\lambda^p=1$; therefore

$$\lambda=e^{i k 2\pi/p}$$

for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let us take an example: consider the following permutation decomposed into the product of two disjoint support cycles

a cycle $\color{red}{(5 4 3 2 1)}$ of order $5$ and a cycle $\color{blue}{(6 7 8)}$ of order $3$.

Its associated matrix is:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|ccc}
0 & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & 0\end{array}\right)$$

Its cycle structure is reflected (see picture) into the five eigenvalues $\color{red}{e^{2i k\pi/5}}$ and the three eigenvalues $\color{blue}{e^{2i k\pi/3}}$.

Please note that eigenvalue $1$ is - in a natural way - a double eigenvalue, and more generally with multiplicity $m$ if the permutation can be decomposed into $m$ disjoint cycles.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

A permutation may be written as a unique product of primitive cycles $\pi = (c_1)\cdots(c_k)$. This corresponds to writing the matrix in block form with each cycle representing a block. Each cycle of length $|c_i|$ has precisely the $|c_i|$'th roots of unity as eigenvalues. This tells you at least precisely when a collection of eigenvalues (with multiplicity) may correspond to a permutation matrix.

Comment: [+1] thorough analysis.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Can we find out minimal polynomial of given permutation matrix with this information?

Comment: @Ibs Note sure. But testing on examples it looks as if it is the product of $(1-t^{|c_i|})$ over distinct cycle lengths.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh can you please tell me the name of book where I can find these properties of Permutation matrix,I will be thankful to you!

Comment: @Ibs You may have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265988/how-do-you-determine-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-permutation-matrix-based for a bit more explanations. I don't really have any book which gives these properties of permutation matrices. I personally fancy P.M.Cohn Algebra vol 1 (end 2) but it doesn't describe the above (and the books are on a bit advanced level)

Comment: @Ibs Searching with google for 'characteristic polynomial for permutation matrices' also gives some interesting items. In an article I found some possibly useful references: N. Jacobson "Basic Algebra I" and S.Lang "Algebra" (but I haven't read them myself).

Comment: @HH Rugh ,thanks a lot!,it was useful to me